# Is it possible to suppress Run Settings output by nunit console?

Tags: nunit

NUnit console outputs run settings, which include the Test Parameters. I do not want it displayed. Is it possible? I use nunit3-console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no options to change the default console text output, which is aimed at immediate developer feedback rather than reporting. Choices for you would be

1. Direct the output to a text file and edit it, perhaps automatically.
2. Create your own report from the XML result file, which contains all the necessary components. You can do this either by writing a resfoundult writer extension to the engine or creating an XSL transform that produces the result you want. I've generally found it best to just pick the technology (C# vs XSLT) that you most enjoy. :-)

Comment: " resfoundult writer extension " ?

Comment: resultwriter extension

Comment: If you need an example of a resultwriter extension, take a look at the NUnit v2 result writer itself. It takes output from NUnit 3 and formats it as an XML result using the V2 format.